# IAR Pe550 variable was set but not never used

Tags: compiler-construction, warnings, workbench, iar

IAR workbench 6.50.6.4958

IAR worbench common 6.5.9.2707

We have a macro

```
 #define NOT_USED(p) ((void)(p))
```

Which is used to make sure the IAR (C) compiler would not issue a warning that the variable is not used, which works fine.

However this macro seems not to be working for the C++ compiler, the compiler 
still report a warning that this variable is unused.

Should the macro look different for C++ or do we need to guard the variables wich some sort of #pragma directive ?

/Stefan

Comment: Why not exclude the declaration all together when the variable isn't used, using `#if` or `#ifdef`:s?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem myself.  The only solution I found for the time being was referenced over in some [Renesas documentation](http://documentation.renesas.com/doc/DocumentServer/U19485EE1V0IF00.pdf) that specifically refers to the IAR C++ compiler.  There is a pragma that can be used to turn off that warning, but it has to be applied to the declaration of the offending variable.  It can't be applied in quite the same manner as the NOT_USED macro you defined, which is unfortunate.  I tried for a little bit to come up with a more cross platform solution, but nothing was coming to mind right away.  If you do want a macro form, you need to use the operator expression form for pragmas which allow you to embed a pragma inside a macro expansion, for example:

```
#include <cstdint>

#if defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#define NOT_USED(var_declaration)        \
    _Pragma("diag_suppress=Pe177,Pe550") \
    var_declaration                      \
    _Pragma("diag_default=Pe177,Pe550")
#else // !defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#define NOT_USED(var_declaration) var_declaration
#endif

int main() {
    NOT_USED(int32_t foo;)
    NOT_USED(int32_t bar = 0;)
    NOT_USED(const int32_t baz = 1;)
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have not tried this macro on a non-IAR compiler, but I'm reasonably certain that it will not interfere successfully in that case.  I'm a bit disappointed that I was unable to come up with a solution that works in a cross platform way that could be substituted in for the NOT_USED macro you showed, especially since that works for the C compiler.  Perhaps this is worth a bug report/feature request to IAR Systems, since it seems to be a discrepancy between their two products.

Comment: I confirm the proposed solution does work with IAR ANSI C/C++ Compiler V9.10.2.313/W64 for ARM.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the __root attribute in IAR when declaring unused global variables.

Comment: __root force the compiler to not optimize and allocate the variable even if it is not used. It's a waste of memory to use it just to remove a warning

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but I think that the following macro is more simple and flexible

```
#define NOT_USED __attribute__((unused))

NOT_USED int32_t foo;  // NO warning if not used
int32_t bar;  // warning if not used
```

It requires the extended language mode in IAR